# RxAndroid: Is there a clean way to get a Subscriber object from an Observable?

Tags: android, observable, subscription, rx-android

So from my view model I call my Observable in another class:

```
 getAuthentication.kickoff()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<RxOkHttpResponse>() {
                @Override
                public final void onCompleted(  ) {
                    getAlbums();
                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                    userMsgHandler.showToast(mParent,mParent.getString(R.string.error_cannot_authenticate));
                }

                @Override
                public final void onNext(RxOkHttpResponse response) {

                    mSubscription = response.subscription;

                }
            });
```

So this call obviously returns an Observable. So I'm wondering what the cleanest way to call subscriber.unsubscribe() on this Observable that is returned or if there even is a way (Right now I return it in onNext -- but I'm not happy bout that)

So is there a way to format the code to store .subscribe() in a member variable:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            mSubscriber = .subscribe(new Subscriber<RxOkHttpResponse>() {

...
```

I'm using v 1.1.0

Comment: @John O'Reilly ...Yes but how to return that call into a member variable and keep same code format?

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment as it was getting long as I was editing it!  Moved it to answer below.  Not sure I understand your question though?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you're using RxJava 1 or 2.  In case of RxJava 1 `subscribe()` will return `Subscription` instance which you can then call `unsubscribe()` on.  However for RxJava 2 I believe you need to add `onSubscribe()`

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax I was looking for:

```
mSubscriber = ( getAuthentication.kickoff()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ).subscribe(new Subscriber<RxOkHttpResponse>() {

          ...
```

Now I can easily store mSubscriber in my view model for clean up triggered by OnDestroy() in my Activity